# Error message box with: This application can't be activated when UAC is disabled

Tags: pdf, uac

I am running Windows 8.1 64-bit. Whenever I click on a **PDF** URL link it wont open.

Instead I get this error message  `This application can't be activated when UAC is disabled`.

I have switched my `UAC` level to **enable** and switched off and rebooted and I get the same message when I click on a **PDF** URL. Anyone help me please?

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you are also unable to start the Reader metro app from the start screen, not just when clicking **PDF** URLs. If UAC is turned off it is not possible to start any metro apps.

Make sure that `UAC` is turned on in the registry (`regedit`). It is controlled by the following registry value:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000001
```

**1** means that it is turned on. You need to *reboot* if you change the value.

An alternative solution is to install a desktop PDF reader (for example: **Adobe Reader** or **Foxit Reader**) and make it the default program to open PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

If u change your local account to your Microsoft Account,u can use these apps even UAC is disabled.
I had this issue for jpg files too, but when i logged in to my Microsoft Account i didn't see the error massage again.